# Is it possible to provide multiple overlays in 'all.json' and 'calculateroute.json' requests using HERE Fleet Telematics API?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps, heremap-navigation

Request samples:

`https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?representation=display&routeAttributes=summary&alternatives=0&mapMatchTolerance=50&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&app_id=myid&apikey=mykey&app_code=mycode&arrival=2018-05-12T12:20:00&departure=2018-05-12T08:00:05&overlays=OVERLAYROAD1,OVERLAYROAD2,OVERLAYROAD3`

`https://fleet.api.here.com/2/search/all.json?app_id=myid&apikey=mykey&app_code=mycode&layer_id=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCn&map_name=OVERLAYROAD1,OVERLAYROAD2,OVERLAYROAD3&geom=full&acceptMissingLayers=true&meta=1`

Request returns 200, but I can't verify it on the map

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the overlays parameter only in calculateroute.json and not in the all.json.

You can find the same in the  api-reference.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html